# Who's the "Author" of the integrating factor method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-history

I've always been interested in how someone discovered this method, it felt pretty magical when I first learnt it, and I've been wondering who discovered/how was it derived for *the first time*.

Does anyone here happen to know this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integrating factor is referred to as Euler's multiplier in honour of Euler for using it to reduce second order equations. See [J. Sasser. “History of Ordinary Differential Equations: the First Hundred Years”,](http://www2.fiu.edu/~yuasun/ODE_History.pdf)

He used as the base $c$ not  the natural logarithm $e$ as is used today.

But the notion of multiplying by an "integrating factor" was also used earlier by  Bernouli,  using $$\frac{x}{y^2}$$  to reduce the first order equation $$2ydx-xdy = 0$$ to $$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{x^2}{y}) = 0$$  See [Mathematical Time Capsules, MAA, page 212](http://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/mathematical-time-capsules)

EDIT:

As suggested in comment by user @A.G., it has its roots with Leibniz as well.

By 1694, Leibniz solved the general first order equation $m dx + n y dx + dy= 0$, where $m, n$ are functions of $x$, by introducing $$\frac{1}{p}dp = n dx$$ which is in modern terms $p = e^{\int n dx}$. Now, the ODE becomes $p m dx + (y p)' = 0$, i.e. $$y = -\frac{\int p(x) m(x) dx}{p}$$

See Chapter 17, A History of Mathematics, Victor Katz.

Comment: Thanks! So the first ever published use of the method would be that one by Leibniz in 1694?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD "First ever" with absolute confidence is a claim I wouldn't dare make. But I'd say probably he was, based on support for, and lack of evidence to the contrary, in the few books/articles on the topic. Also the fact that Leibniz is as old as the history of differential equations itself.

Comment: It is difficult to track the authorship in first place because that time authors deliberately hid their techniques in publications and often stated only results without details to protect their methods. But Leibniz-Bernoulli is a good guess I would say, they knew all the elementary differentiation techniques including [separation variables and variation of parameters](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/2/Parker-CMJ-2014.pdf).

Comment: @A.G. Excellent point. And a very interesting article as well, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

About the name of the method:

> INTEGRATING FACTOR is found in May 1845 in a paper by Sir George Gabriel Stokes published in the Cambridge Mathematical Journal [University of Michigan Historical Math Collection].

([Source](http://jeff560.tripod.com/i.html))

About the development of the method:

> This capsule offers some differential equations solved by the
>   originators of the technique of using an integrating factor, though
>   they did not use that expression. (..) Memorizing the formula would
>   not be in the spirit of the originators of the method, Johann
>   Bernoulli (1667–1748) and Leonhard Euler (1707–1783), (..)

([Source](http://universitypublishingonline.org/maa/chapter.jsf?bid=CBO9780883859841&cid=CBO9780883859841A207))

Comment: I think as early as 1700's by Euler (It is, afterall also referred to as Euler's multiplier)

Comment: I am pretty sure that Bernoulli and Leibniz were aware of the method in late 1600's. Perhaps Newton too. Euler used it more systematically to reduce second order DE to first order ones.